# reduce with empty set as initial value

Tags: python

I have a list of list and I want to construct a set out of the elements present in all the sublists..

example :  `a = [[1,2],[2,3]]` should give `set([1,2,3])`

I tried reduce(lambda x,y:x.update(y),a,set([])) but it raises `AttributeError: 'NoneType'` object has no attribute 'update'

Can someone tell me how to do this using reduce function ?

Comment: Answerede here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python with TIME BENCHMARKS

Comment: @andilabs That link does not answer this question. That link shows how to perform a similar operation on lists using basic `for` loops. This question pertains to `reduce` not finding its initialized value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `update()` on a set returns `None`, not the set. This is documented and expected behavior. Assuming you want to use `update()` for some reason, you could write your lambda as follows:

```
 lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x
```

The `or` clause returns `x` if the first clause is "falsy" (which `None` is).

Really, though, I think you want to use `union()` instead of `update()`. It does mostly the same thing and returns the result.

```
lambda x, y: x.union(y)
```

BTW, you can just write `set()` to get an empty set, you don't need `set([])`. So the rewritten `reduce()` would be:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), a, set())
```

Others have posted additional options, each of which has value for making you think about how they work.

Comment: The thing is, `set.union` accepts `*args`, so you don't need a `reduce` at all. `set([]).union(*a)` is all you need.

Comment: Yeah, that is a further improvement but I assumed the `reduce()` was a requirement.

Answer (score 16):

As requested:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,3]]
>>> reduce(lambda s, elems: s.union(elems), a, set())
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Another way just for fun:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain.from_iterable(a))
set([1, 2, 3])
```

And one more just to be cool:

```
>>> set.union(set(), *a)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: @julio.alegria My first version used ``|`` but it looked like a weird separator in the context of ``reduce(lambda s, elems: s | elems, a, set())``.  To my eyes, it looks like something that divides ``elem, a, set()`` from the lambda expression.

Comment: Fix your last example, there should be `set` instead of `s`.

Comment: have a look on TIME benchmarks here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: note that you'll have to import "functools" in order to use the reduce function via functools.reduce

Answer (score 2):

Kindall already answered how to accomplish this task with `reduce()` but I think it's less clunky to do it with `itertools.chain.from_iterable()`:

```
import itertools

a = [[1, 2], [2, 3]]

print set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
```

Comment: +1 and this is extremly fast! Have a look on benchmarks here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
c =set();
reduce(lambda x,y:c.update(y),a,c)
```

Its a set that you are using. Since set([]).update doesn't return a value, and reduce function uses the return from previous operation. It raises a Nonetype has no attribute update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `set.update()` is that returns `None` and `itertools` .. there has to be a better solution. And there is! I think this is way cleaner:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,3]]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) | set(y), a)
set([1, 2, 3])
```

**Note:** `|` makes a union between sets.

Answer (score 0):

And another one with pure list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[2,3]]
>>> set([item for sublist in a for item in sublist])
{1, 2, 3}
```

which is what [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) is about.